# undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, methods, render, local

I'm trying to render a page from layout to my movies index but the thing is when I put the code in the index it works fine but when I move it to layouts, it shows me `undefined local variable or method 'movie'`
this is my controller:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all.order(:cached_votes_score => :desc)
end

def show
end

def new
  @movie = current_user.movies.build
  @movie = Movie.new 
  @categories = Category.all
end
def edit
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end

def create
  @movie = current_user.movies.build(movie_params)
  @movie.category_id = params[:category_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @movie.save
      format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end

def update
  @movie.category_id = params[:category_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @movie.update(movie_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

 def destroy
   @movie.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end

def upvote
  @movie.upvote_from current_user, :vote_weight => 3
  redirect_to root_path
end

def downvote
  @movie.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

and this is my index page:

```
<div class= "row">
 <% @movies.each do |movie|%>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= link_to (image_tag movie.image.url(:medium), class: 'image'), movie %>
      <%= render 'layouts/vote' %> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the page i want to render it `layouts/vote`:

```
 <%= link_to like_movie_path(movie), class: "like", method: :put do %>
  <button type= "button" class = "btn btn-info" aria-label= "Left Align">
   <span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up glyphicon-align-center" aria-hidden= "true"></span>
  <span class= "badge"><%= movie.get_upvotes.size%></span>
 </button>
<%end%>
<%= link_to dislike_movie_path(movie), class: "like", method: :put do %>
<button type= "button" class = "btn btn-info" aria-label= "Left Align">
<span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down glyphicon-align-center" aria-hidden= "true"></span>
<span class= "badge"><%= movie.get_downvotes.size%></span>
</button>
<%end%>
```

so i got an error undefined local variable or method `movie'
for this line:

```
<%= link_to like_movie_path(movie), class: "like", method: :put do %>
```

And the routes:

```
like_movie PUT    /movies/:id/like(.:format)     movies#upvote
dislike_movie PUT    /movies/:id/dislike(.:format)  movies#downvote
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `movie` object as a local variable to the partial

```
<%= render 'layouts/vote', movie: movie %>
```

Comment: it works fine but what if i want to render from different place like i have category and i'd like render the same page i tried same but it doesn't work

Comment: Say if you're trying to render this in a different view, all you need is to pass in a `movie` object. So, if it doesn't work, probably `movie` is not set to the right object.